# laravel scout when does shouldBeSearchable get triggered

Tags: laravel, algolia, searchable, laravel-scout

Lets say I have a `shouldBeSearchable()` set like this:

```
public function shouldBeSearchable()
{
    return $this->is_active === 1;
}
```

By default in my app a newly created post gets **is_active** set to **1** so it will be added to my search index.

But if I now update that same post and set **is_active** to **0** does it automatically then get removed from my search index?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it should. 
If it doesn't work, it will be a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Run `php artisan scout:flush "App\Models\YourModel"`.
Then run `php artisan scout:import "App\Models\YourModel`.